# opencv detecting barcode on an image

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv to get a barcode contour from an image.

Here is the input image:
[image]

So far I have tried to convert it to grayscale, then blur and finally use adaptive threshold. This is what it looks like:
[image]

And the result of contour detection...
[image]

I don't really need to decode the barcode, reading the numbers is just fine. But the numbers are angled and the image is coloured.
Any ways of reading the numbers only?

Comment: "I don't really need to decode the barcode, reading the numbers is just fine" - ehh, wouldn't "reading the numbers" be equivalent to "decoding the barcode". They are the same thing (unless someone is playing tricks on you).

Comment: Sure. I mean I don't need to specifically read/decode the lines from a picture.

Comment: the whole point of the barcode is, that it is easier to get the values via image recognition.

Comment: @skeller What kind of image recognition can I use in this case?

Comment: @EgorChubarov starting point could be http://opencv-tutorials-hub.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-scan-barcodes-qr-codes-with-opencv-using-zbar.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So far I have only come to conclusion that  there are no simple means of reading a barcode from such an image. I came across some methods that were supposed to work but it seems that they are only good under ideal conditions when the barcode is parallel to the image borders with all lines clearly seen. Even some apps on the phone have some hard time trying to read these barcodes.

It was decided that I should switch to using [QR codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) instead. Methods like the one that skeller [suggested in the comments](http://opencv-tutorials-hub.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-scan-barcodes-qr-codes-with-opencv-using-zbar.html) should work just fine.